# Difference in "dir" between Python 2 and 3

Tags: python

The following code behaves differently in Python 2 and Python 3, and I'm not sure why.

```
class Dataset(object):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if not item in dir(self):
            print(item)

a = Dataset()
a.Hello
```

The result in Python 3:

```
> Hello
```

The result in Python 2:

```
__members__
__members__
__methods__
...
```

ad infinitum until a recursion ceiling is reached. What is the difference in the behavior of "dir"?

Edit: And is there a workaround?  self.**dict** is the obvious choice but it doesn't include functions which turns out to be a problem in my code.

Comment: Actually, `__getattr__()` [isn't supposed to be called at all](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) if the attribute is already present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for `dir` in Python 2.7 and 3.5 seems identical - there are no implementation details. But clearly, `dir()` in Python 2 invokes `__getattr__` causing the infinite recursion.

However, both documentation sets do say that

> Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class.

That note about it being a convenience is significant.

If you modify your `__getattr__` to look at `self.__dict__` instead of using `dir()`,the problem goes away.

```
In [5]: class Dataset(object):
          def __getattr__(self, item):
            if not item in self.__dict__:
              print(item)
   ...:             

In [6]: a = Dataset()

In [7]: a.Hello
Hello
```

Comment: Didn't see the edit about functions until after i posted the answer

Comment: AFAIR, `dir()` tries to lookup `__dir__`. Since that one doesn't exist, `__getattr__()` is called. Which calls `dir()` ...

Answer (score 3):

Without examining the source code, I can't say *why* this happens (although I have some hypotheses), but here is a pretty simple workaround:

```
class Dataset(object):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            super(Dataset, self).__getattr__(item)
        except AttributeError:
            print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not needed to check that `if not item in dir(self)` inside `def __getattr__`

`__getattr__` won't be called if item is listed in dir(self)
You can have your code as

```
class Dataset(object):
    x = 12
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print(item)

a = Dataset()
a.Hello  # print Hello
a.x      # return 12
```